# How to exlude packageScanning using application.properties?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm using a spring boot with hibernate. I want to exclude one class from component scanning.
I can do it by using **@SpringBootApplication(exclude = HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)**.
I don't want to hardcode it in my application. But I want to give those properties in `application.properties`.

Does spring boot provide any options for that?

Answer (score 1):

As it's stated in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-disabling-specific-auto-configuration):

> you can also control the list of auto-configuration classes to exclude by using the `spring.autoconfigure.exclude` property.